Any direct method to show that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}]=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}]$?
We know that Galois extension is simple extension, so the splitting field of $(X^2-2)(X^2-3)(X^2-5)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfies $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}]=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}]$.
From the proof of the theorem that finite separable extension is simple we can see that $\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3}+ \sqrt{5}$ is one. But is there some direct method to show this?

Let $a=\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5$. One can expand every power $a^k$ into an explicit linear combination of $1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt6,\sqrt{10},\sqrt{15},\sqrt{30}$, the coefficients of which define a map to a vector $c_k \in \Bbb Z^8$. (Then $c_0,\dots,c_8$ must be linearly dependent, and finding a nontrivial relation among them is a way of finding a minimal polynomial for $a$.) Here, one can find a linear combination of $c_0,\dots,c_7$ that equals the image of $\sqrt2$ in $\Bbb Z^8$, and this proves that $\sqrt2\in\Bbb Q(a)$—and similarly for $\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt5$.

There are infinitely many values $\theta$ such that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}]=\mathbb Q(\theta)$ (Primitive element theorem).The asked question here is about a direct method to prove that   $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$  is  such one $\theta$. Is for this that I think the best answer is given by Greg Martin's comment.

@GregMartin
Let $ \alpha = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 +  \sqrt 5.$  Then
$$ \frac{5\alpha}{3} - \frac{7\alpha^3}{72} -  \frac{7\alpha^5}{144} + \frac{\alpha^7}{576}  = \sqrt 2, $$
$$ \frac{15\alpha}{4} - \frac{61\alpha^3}{24} +  \frac{37\alpha^5}{96} - \frac{\alpha^7}{96}  = \sqrt 3, $$
$$ -\frac{53\alpha}{12} + \frac{95\alpha^3}{36} -  \frac{97\alpha^5}{288} + \frac{5\alpha^7}{576}  = \sqrt 5 $$

I'll assume we know that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}]$ is Galois of degree $8$ with Galois group $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ acting by independently flipping signs of the three generators. Then $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}] \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}]$, so the Galois orbit of $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$ contains $\pm\sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{3} \pm \sqrt{5}$. One checks that these 8 numbers are distinct, so we conclude that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$ has degree at least $8$, hence exactly $8$ since $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}]$ is contained in a degree $8$ extension.

In principle, you could simply calculate the coordinates of $\alpha^0, \alpha^1, \alpha^2, \ldots, \alpha^7$ with respect to the basis $\{ 1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{6}, \sqrt{10}, \sqrt{15}, \sqrt{30} \}$ of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $\alpha = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$.  Assuming $\alpha$ is indeed a primitive root, the resulting $8\times 8$ matrix will be invertible.  Once you calculate that the matrix is invertible, then that implies that every element of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}]$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of $\alpha^0, \ldots, \alpha^7$.  In particular, for example, the second column of the inverse will give coefficients for a polynomial in $\alpha$ which equals $\sqrt{2}$.
(Of course, in practice, it would be likely to be helpful to use a CAS to assist with the details of this calculation.)

You win by posting an answer instead of comment! but for the record I beat you by three seconds ;) +1

Let $ \alpha = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 +  \sqrt 5.$  Then
$$ \frac{5\alpha}{3} - \frac{7\alpha^3}{72} -  \frac{7\alpha^5}{144} + \frac{\alpha^7}{576}  = \sqrt 2, $$
$$ \frac{15\alpha}{4} - \frac{61\alpha^3}{24} +  \frac{37\alpha^5}{96} - \frac{\alpha^7}{96}  = \sqrt 3, $$
$$ -\frac{53\alpha}{12} + \frac{95\alpha^3}{36} -  \frac{97\alpha^5}{288} + \frac{5\alpha^7}{576}  = \sqrt 5 $$

naming x = sqrt(2). y = sqrt(3), z = sqrt(5)  and
a = x + y + z
led to this, so far
x^2 = 2  ,  y^2 = 3 , z^2 =  5

? a
%6 = x + (y + z)
? a2
%7 = (2*y + 2*z)*x + (2*z*y + 10)
? a3
%8 = (6*z*y + 26)*x + (24*y + 20*z)
? 
? a4
%11 = (80*y + 64*z)*x + (56*z*y + 224)

? a5
%14 = (200*z*y + 784)*x + (664*y + 520*z)
? 
? a6
%17 = (2448*y + 1904*z)*x + (1584*z*y + 6160)
? 


? a7
%20 = (5936*z*y + 23024)*x + (18976*y + 14720*z)
? 

The convenient ordered basis, including tyhe way Pari/gp orders variables  would be
$$   1,  x, y, z,  yx, zx, zy, xyz$$
so that the row for $a^7$    comes out
$$  0, 23024, 18976, 14720, 0, 0, 0, 5936  $$
Let $ \alpha = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 +  \sqrt 5.$  Then
$$ \frac{5\alpha}{3} - \frac{7\alpha^3}{72} -  \frac{7\alpha^5}{144} + \frac{\alpha^7}{576}  = \sqrt 2, $$
$$ \frac{15\alpha}{4} - \frac{61\alpha^3}{24} +  \frac{37\alpha^5}{96} - \frac{\alpha^7}{96}  = \sqrt 3, $$
$$ -\frac{53\alpha}{12} + \frac{95\alpha^3}{36} -  \frac{97\alpha^5}{288} + \frac{5\alpha^7}{576}  = \sqrt 5 $$
Sanity check with Pari/gp and decimals
? a = sqrt(2) + sqrt(3)  + sqrt(5)  
%1 = 5.3823323474417620387383087344468466810
? 
? 
? x2= (5/3) * a -(7/72) * a^3 - (7/144) * a^5  +(1/576) * a^7
%2 = 1.4142135623730950488016887242096980784
? x2^2
%3 = 1.9999999999999999999999999999999999995
? 
? 
? y3 = (15/4) * a -(61/24) * a^3 + (37/96) * a^5  -(1/96) * a^7
%4 = 1.7320508075688772935274463415058723703
? y3^2
%5 = 3.0000000000000000000000000000000000116
? 
? 
? z5 = -(53/12) * a +(95/36) * a^3 - (97/288) * a^5  +(5/576) * a^7
%6 = 2.2360679774997896964091736687312762291
? z5^2
%7 = 4.9999999999999999999999999999999999717
? 
? 


This is Greg Martin's comment and  Daniel Schepler's answer plus a good calculator.

This method goes back to Lagrange:  consider $P(x)$ the Lagrange interpolation  polynomial for the nodes $(\epsilon_1 \sqrt{2}+\epsilon_2 \sqrt{3}+\epsilon_3 \sqrt{5}, \epsilon_1 \sqrt{2})$, where $\epsilon_1$,$\epsilon_2$, $\epsilon_3 \in \{-1,1\}$ ($8$ nodes). By symmetry the polynomial will have coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. In fact
$$P(x) = \frac{1}{576} x(x^6-28x^4-56x^2+960)$$
as one can check.
$\bf{Added:}$ Since @Will Jagy did check the first one, let's add the interpolation polynomials for $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{5}$.
$$P_2(x) = \frac{15 x}{4}-\frac{61 x^3}{24}+\frac{37 x^5}{96}-\frac{x^7}{96}$$
$$P_3(x)=-\frac{53 x}{12} + \frac{95 x^3}{36} -\frac{97x^5}{288}+\frac{5x^7}{576}$$
$\bf{Added:}$ While the interpolating polynomial might appear like "numerical analysis", in this case it is really algebra. Say we are looking for a polynomial $P$ of degree $\le 7$ such that
$$P(\epsilon _1 \sqrt{2}+ \epsilon_2 \sqrt{3}+\epsilon_3 \sqrt{5}) = \epsilon_1 \sqrt{2}$$
This is equivalent to : the polynomial $P(u+v+w) - u$ is in the polynomial ideal $(u^2-2,v^2-3,w^2-5)$. So reduce $P(u+v+w) - u$ and get an expression sum of $1$, $u$, $v$, $\ldots$, $u v w$ ( $8$ terms) with some coefficients. Now make all of the coefficients $0$ and get $P$.

Good. We agree on the first one. I got: Let $ \alpha = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 +  \sqrt 5.$  Then
$$ \frac{5\alpha}{3} - \frac{7\alpha^3}{72} -  \frac{7\alpha^5}{144} + \frac{\alpha^7}{576}  = \sqrt 2, $$
$$ \frac{15\alpha}{4} - \frac{61\alpha^3}{24} +  \frac{37\alpha^5}{96} - \frac{\alpha^7}{96}  = \sqrt 3, $$
$$ -\frac{53\alpha}{12} + \frac{95\alpha^3}{36} -  \frac{97\alpha^5}{288} + \frac{5\alpha^7}{576}  = \sqrt 5 $$

@Will Jagy: looks good!

Another check, adding my left hand sides gives $12 \alpha / 12$  while the right sand sides sum to $\alpha,$  the other powers cancel out on the left.
